# Are variables in array sizes allowed in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, size, curly-braces

I'm using the GCC compiler on Linux. I don't understand how variables work in array sizes.

When I run:

```
char string[6];
string[0] = 'h';
printf("%s", string);
```

As expected, it outputs: h

If I run:

```
int x = 1;
char string[5 + x];
string[0] = 'h';
printf("%s", string);
```

it outputs h followed by � and other random characters. I guess it's accessing memory addresses, it's not supposed to. The characters are different every time, it's run.

When I do the same but replace line two with "char string[5 + x] = {}"
It errors: variable-sized object may not be initialized.

If I do the same with an integer array, it works perfectly fine if I type "int array[5 + x] = {};" but not "int array[5 + x]"

Are variables allowed in the size declarations of int arrays, but not in char arrays/strings?

Comment: The problem isn't the variable. The problem is that you never added a null terminator. Both versions have this error, you just got lucky in the first one.

Comment: Add `string[1] = '\0';` to both programs.

Comment: You cannot assume that any array declared in a function will be initialized meaningfully unless you do it yourself explicitly.

Comment: Variable length arrays (VLAs) can be used for any type, including `char` arrays that are used for strings. What you apparently need to study is how strings work in C. Strings in C have a lot of non-intuitive features, so you really need a good reference that explains strings in detail.

Comment: "As expected, it outputs: h" In fact, that is not really to be expected. Assuming the first code lines are part of a function, the array will not be initialized to 0. That means only the first element contains a specific value while the other elements hold indetermined content.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments, your problem is that the below invokes undefined behavior.

> ```
> int x = 1;
> char string[5 + x];
> string[0] = 'h';
> printf("%s", string);
> ```

The undefined behaviour stems from using `string` *as a string.* Strings in C require a null terminating character to signal the end of the string. Your variable length array has not been initialized (apart from the first character) so the contents are indeterminate. You have a `5 + x` sized chunk of memory, but that memory could be in any state.

In the first case, `string[1]` was clearly `0`, thus null-terminating the string. This is not guaranteed as you can see from the second example where `printf` printed gibberish because it didn't see the next character after `'h'` being a null terminator.

With a static-sized array we would initialize it with `{0}` or `{}` to set the contents to zero, but VLAs may not be initialized this way.

Comment: Note that in C23, it will be possible to use `= {};` to default initialize a VLA (or any other variable type).  This is a big, beneficial change; at least you'll be able to zero the array succinctly, instead of having to use a call to `memset()` or equivalent.  However, this is the only type of initializer that will be allowed for a VLA.

Answer (score 2):

To address the titled part of OP's concern:

> Are variables in array sizes allowed in C?

Before C99: [Variable length arrays (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not standard.

C99: Standard

C11, C17: If `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined, then no VLA support.
otherwise VLAs are supported.

C23: (At least how it is currently proposed.) Like C11, C17. "usage of VLA type is allowed except creating VLA object with automatic duration ... which is optional." per `__STDC_NO_VLA__`. [@tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247485/are-variables-in-array-sizes-allowed-in-c/77248026?noredirect=1#comment136184578_77248026)

---

> Are variables allowed in the size declarations of `int` arrays, but not in `char` arrays/strings?

If allowed for one type, VLA allowed for all array types.

---

`printf("%s", string);` is bad code as `"%s"` expect a pointer to a *string*.  `string` is not a *string* as it does not certainly contains a *null character*.  Result: *Undefined behavior* (UB).

Comment: "except a VLA in a function prototype". It is confusing. It should be that any usage of VLA type is *allowed* except creating VLA object with automatic duration (aka on stack) which is optional.

Comment: @tstanisl — Since you can't create statically allocated VLAs either (never could), it means that VLAs can only be allocated dynamically (via `malloc()` et al).  However, ordinary arrays can be passed to functions that handle arrays with variable sizes, so they are treated as a VLA in the function, even though in the calling code, they are regular arrays.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, technically speaking one can make a `static` pointer to VLA. `void foo(int n) { static int (*arr)[n]; }`. At file scope VLAs cannot be used because it is not possible to form any VLA type without code execution.